# calculate Geometric progression in Ruby

Tags: ruby, math

What's the best way to calculate a geometric progression in Ruby?

Are there any built-in methods available?

Should I use some math gem?

Or should I implement my own small function?

Comment: What inputs and outputs do you want?

Comment: 3 params as input: `initial value`, `ratio`, `number of iterations`; output - an `array` of values. _But_ making the function yourself will imply that nothing pre-implemented exists and it might be the wrong answer, as I don't think that I'm the first one calculating geometric progression in Ruby

Comment: While you're certainly not the first Ruby programmer to ever need a geometric progression, it's likely that nobody's ever really bothered to compartmentalize it because it's such a simplistic operation. A geometric progression is essentially just the repeated application of an exponent, so as long as a programming language supports exponentiation, it practically supports geometric progressions out of the box.

Comment: as answers demonstrate even simplistic operation implementations can significantly differ in terms of performance and probably other nuances, so I'm always trying to use proven and tested libs when possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the task is complicated enough to expect an external library.

I feel that this might be more efficient than ranksrejoined's answer:

```
def geo_prog a, r, n
    (n - 1).times.inject([a]){|a| a << a.last * r}
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just want the values and not some sort of fractional display, it's as simple as creating a function that takes the initial value (with 1 as a sensible default), the ratio to progress by, and‒at least in my example‒how many elements of the progressive sequence you'd like to get back.

```
def geo_prog(a = 1, r, n)
  (0...n).map { |e| a * r ** e }
end
```

Comment: Your answer and mine are complementary, I think. When the n is small, your answer is faster. When n gets larger, my answer is faster.

Comment: @ranksrejoined sorry I didn't measure it with smaller numbers, my fault

Answer (score 0):

By geometric progression I presume you mean a sequence, in general
(Note I am using ^ to represent an exponent)

```
a*r^0 + a*r^1 + a*r^2 + ... + a*r^n
```

a real example might be a=10 r=0.5 which would give us

```
10 + 5 + 2.5 + 1.25 + ...
```

If the progression tends to a value (i.e. it converges) You can calculate the value with a very nice formula

```
a / (1 - r)
```

However this is not always the case, sometimes it might not converge, or you may only wish to do 10 so iterations. In which case you can use.

```
a*(1 - r^(n+1)) / (1 - r)
```

On a side note it may be helpful to add, that the sequence will only converge when r < 1

Comment: Nice to see that at least one person was paying attention in school. Iteratively computing something that has a simple and well known non-iterative solution is a bit silly. I'd give you two upvotes if I could. I'm guessing that `n` is finite so you don't have to worry about convergence but mentioning it was a nice touch anyway.

Comment: @muistooshort This is not what was asked. The expected return value is an array that includes the first n terms as indicated in the comment to the question.

Comment: Apologies, I did not see the comment stating that an array of values was expected, but I do hope this helps someone who wishes to calculate  just one point in the sequence, or the value it tends to.